# Polygon fill color not working properly (React Native maps)

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-native, polygon, react-native-ios

I am using **Google Maps** on iOS and I have Polygons. (react-native-maps)

Before update *(to version 0.18.3. - at the moment I am not able to update to latest version)* everything works properly, but from now fill color gets weird results.

Sometimes color is ok, sometimes it is not proper, no rules.

On android everything works well.

```
export const Polygon = (props) => {
    return (
        <MapView.Polygon
            coordinates={ props.selectedAreas }
            fillColor={ props.fillColor }
            strokeColor={ props.strokeColor }
        />
    )
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked for me using the fix from https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/3025#issuecomment-538345230

```
import React from 'react';
import { Polygon } from 'react-native-maps';

function CustomPolygon({ onLayout, ...props }) {
  const ref = React.useRef();

  function onLayoutPolygon() {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.setNativeProps({ fillColor: props.fillColor });
    }
    // call onLayout() from the props if you need it
  }

  return <Polygon ref={ref} onLayout={onLayoutPolygon} {...props} />;
}

export default CustomPolygon;
```

It is not very pretty but I guess it will have to do until the upstream bug is fixed.